# Three ways of traversing a binary tree recursively in Fsharp F#

Tags: types, tree, f#

I have been reading this great book **Functional Programming Using F#** I have just got to the chapter about finite tree and I noticed that there are three ways of traversing a tree, but I don't understand why and how they are different.
Here is the code.

```
type BinaryTree<'a> =
    |Leaf 
    |Node of BinaryTree<'a> * 'a * BinaryTree<'a>


let rec preorder (tr:BinaryTree<'a>) : 'a list =
    match tr with
    |Leaf            -> []
    |Node(trr,x,trl) -> x:: (preorder trr) @ (preorder trl) 


let rec inorder (tree:BinaryTree<'a>) : 'a list =
    match tree with
    |Leaf -> []
    |Node(tr,x,tl) -> (inorder tr) @ [x] @ (inorder tl)

let rec postorder (tree:BinaryTree<'a>) : 'a list =
    match tree with
    |Leaf -> []
    |Node(tr,x,tl) -> (postorder tr) @ (postorder tl) @ [x]

let someTree = Node(Leaf,20,Node(Leaf,40,Node(Node(Leaf,-2,Leaf),2,Node(Leaf,0,Leaf))))

preorder someTree
inorder someTree
postorder someTree
```

Any Help would be welcome! :)

Comment: If the book actually is great, this is explained in detail in the book, with motivating examples. The difference is the order in which the nodes are collected. (In case you didn't know: "pre" means "before" and "post" means "after".)

Comment: #molbdnilo, lol... I am french speaker in an english world, anyways it talks about them in details but it doesn't say why I should use one in spite of the other... That was my question. if it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the order of concatenation order in the different traversal methods:

Pre: `x :: (preorder tl) @ (preorder tr)`

1. `x` : current value
2. `preorder tl` : visit left tree
3. `preorder tr` : visit right tree

In: `(inorder tl) @ [x] @ (inorder tr)`

1. `inorder tl` : visit left tree
2. `x` : current value
3. `inorder tr` : visit right tree

Post: `(postorder tl) @ (postorder tr) @ [x]`

1. `postorder tl` : visit left tree
2. `postorder tr` : visit right tree
3. `x` : current value

If you trace around your tree anti-clockwise starting at the top (above the root):

- Pre-order traversal returns the elements in the order of where you encounter the left-hand side of each node first.
- In-order traversal returns the elements in the order of where you encounter the bottom of each node first.
- Post-order traversal returns the elements in the order of where you encounter the right-hand side of each node first.

As a brief overview, pre-order traversal is useful for duplicating entire trees, in-order travel is useful for binary searching and post-order traversal is useful for deletion of entire trees.

More details can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Thanks for this nice breakdown

Answer (score 0):

If you run your own code, you will see the difference in results:

```
> preorder someTree;;
val it : int list = [20; 40; 2; -2; 0]
> inorder someTree;;
val it : int list = [20; 40; -2; 2; 0]
> postorder someTree;;
val it : int list = [-2; 0; 2; 40; 20]
```

So, the difference is in order of the list elements.

Comment: It's not god or bad, it solves different tasks: you might need different order depending on what you are going to do with the result